# How to use foreach loop for interest rates?

Tags: javascript

I am trying out something for my banking project, and I am faced with a dilemma.

Given an array of total monthly expenses for first 6 months of the year in order:

```
var exp = [4000, 5000, 6500, 5000, 2800, 3500]
```

use `forEach` loop to traverse the array and add `2%` interest for the months where the amount exceeds `4000`. The interest is only for the amount above `4000`. Store final value in the array and print it.

I can't arrive at the final value, anyone would like to try their code out?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add your code, then we can have a look to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: As a side note: This is fine as a learning project, but please don't use JS for the maths side of any serious banking projects. (JS maths is... quirky)

Comment: If your expected output is array of the same size as the input (you just transform conditionally each item), there's a more better suited method: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which accepts as an argument the function that is executed against each item of input array and its return passed to resulting array.

Comment: Your solution (relatively trivial) would be something, like `const result = exp.map(monthlyExpense => monthlyExpense > 4000 ? monthlyExpense * 1.02 : monthlyExpense)`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Not quite, with respect to "The interest is only for the amount above 4000. Store final value in the array and print it.".

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your array and check if `amount > 4000`. Then calculate the interest and assign the value to array.

```js
var exp = [4000, 5000, 6500, 5000, 2800, 3500];
exp.forEach(function(value, index) {
  if( value > 4000 ){
     let interest = (value*2)/100; // Write your logic here to calculate the interest
     exp[index] = value + interest;
  }
});
console.log(exp);
```